# Cannot access the selected items collection when the ListView is in virtual mode?

Tags: c#, listview, selecteditem, virtualmode

I have a ListView in Virtual Mode. I wanna to access `SelectedItems` property.
But when I use `ListView1.SelectedItems` , I receive the following Exception :

```
Cannot access the selected items collection when the ListView is in virtual mode
```

How can I access to `ListView1.SelectedItems` in VirtualMode.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444727/loop-through-all-elements-in-a-listview-in-virtual-mode

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I've done it by the following code, but it has an exception when more than one item are selected:

> *Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index*

```
List<ListViewItem> ListViewItems = new List<ListViewItem>();

foreach (int index in listView1.SelectedIndices)
{
    ListViewItem SelectedListViewItem = listView1.Items[index];  // exception
    ListViewItems.RemoveAt(index);
}
…

void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item = ListViewItems[e.ItemIndex];
}
```

Whenever you remove item(s) from a collection, always iterate from the largest index to the smallest index, like this:

```
for (int index = listView1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    …
}
```

This is because every time you remove an item in a collection, the index will change if you do not iterate from the largest to the smallest index.

Answer (score 17):

It is quite old post but maybe someone else will benefit.

Simply use `ListView.SelectedIndexCollection col = listView.SelectedIndices;`
Then you can access an item:

```
forearch(var item in col)
{
   string txt = listView.Items[item].Text;
}
```

..but you won't be able to iterate through ListView.Items using foreach because there is no iterator available in this mode. Using indexer is just flying fine :-)

When trying to use foreach you get an exception:

> When the ListView is in virtual mode, you cannot enumerate through the
>   ListView items collection using an enumerator or call GetEnumerator.
>   Use the ListView items indexer instead and access an item by index
>   value.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx)

In virtual mode, the Items collection is disabled. Attempting to access it results in an InvalidOperationException. The same is true of the CheckedItems collection and the SelectedItems collection. If you want to retrieve the selected or checked items, use the SelectedIndices and CheckedIndices collections instead.

Answer (score 0):

I you store all items in list and use this list to give item in RetrieveVirtualItem 
you can find selected items like following

```
Dim lstData As List(Of ListViewItem) = New List(Of ListViewItem)
Dim lstSelectedItems As List(Of ListViewItem) = lstData.FindAll(Function(lstItem As ListViewItem) lstItem.Selected = True)
Me.Text = lstItems.Count.ToString()
```